# Ubuntu Server on Raspberry PI 4: High CPU usage

Tags: server, raspberrypi, cpu-load

I just installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS on Raspberry PI, updated packages and installed Postgres. The device is essentially doing nothing. However, I see in top and uptime outputs: load average: 1.00, 1.00, 1.00. This seems too high to me. And the device seems pretty hot (it's running in [Argon One M.2 case](https://www.argon40.com/argon-one-m-2-case-for-raspberry-pi-4.html) with a cooler). top doesn't show any process with high load. If I start 4 instances of 'yes > /dev/null &' to load all 4 cores I see then load average coming to 4.0. Did anyone face such an issue? And is here an issue? What does uptime report with no apps in Raspbian?

Here is brief information about the system:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-1036-raspi #39-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed May 12 17:37:51 UTC 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

If it matters it's installed on an SSD drive, not on SD card.

Comment: Raspbian shows 0.15. I better switch there.

Comment: Raspberry OS 64 bit, 2021-05-07, with desktop, load average 0.5 0.4 0.22. I guess ubuntu server has some issue.

Comment: Try running the following command, and include the output in your post: `ps aux | (read h; echo "$h"; sort -nr -k 3) | head -11 | less -SEX`